# Using Checkstyle to validate domain object get /sets

Tags: java, checkstyle, pmd

I'm having a problem or looking for a checkstyle rule that will validate the following.  This is a trivial check, but would be a worth while rule when someone manually changes a get/set name.

I want to have a rule that will validate get/sets and error out when something like this is found in the code.

Example: the original attribute was description.  But the developer needs to change it to a shortDescription, but messes up the refactor.

```
private String description;

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setShortDescription(String description) {
   this.description = description;
}
```

Or if there's any other rule engine like Pmd that might capture this.  Or a custom ruleset, I guess I could create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not covered by Checkstyle, if PMD may be an option, there is a [BeanMembersShouldSerialize](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/javabeans.html#BeanMembersShouldSerialize) test, which complains if there are any non-static and non-transient fields which have no getters and setters following the Java naming conventions.

Comment: NICE..!!!  That sounds almost like a close to near perfect solution.  A quick one to validate there are the correct get/sets for each non static variable.  Thanks!!  I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The [standard checkstyle checks](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/availablechecks.html) do not offer something like this, and I don't think such a check makes much sense:

In your example, what error do you expect to be reported? A missing setter for the `description` property? A missing property for the `setShortDescription` setter?

How should checkstyle know the properties for which you want to have getters/setters? I assume you don't want to have getters *and* setters for *all* your private variables.

Comment: I expect it to fail the build when running this type of rule.  The error would be "missing setDescription for internal field description, but found setShortDescription referenced.

In many cases for "pojo / domain" classes, they typically have semantics such as internal "private" only fields, and have an equivelent set/get for each internal variable.  So yes, based on a rule, I'd want every internal domain variable to be checked, except statics.  Possible along the lines of a bean spec.  In a few cases, bugs such as this have leaked in by simple mistakes.  Those mistakes are costly downstream.